Error on Deploy CloudFormation in VSCode Bash
I have been having isues trying to get past this error on my VSCode.
I will appreciate any help.
Thank you.
I am trying to try my hand on asset tracking project built on AWS.
$ chmod +x deploy_cloudformation.sh && export AWS_REGION=us-east-1 && ./deploy_cloudformation.sh Deploying kinesis data stream template for sample app. ./deploy_cloudformation.sh: line 16: aws: command not found Retrieving TrackingAndGeofencingSampleKinesisDataStreamARN from the created CloudFormation stack. ./deploy_cloudformation.sh: line 28: aws: command not found Error: Failed to retrieve TrackingAndGeofencingSampleKinesisDataStreamARN from CloudFormation stack.
This is the deploy_cloudformation.sh:
`*#!/bin/sh
Configurable variables
TrackerName="SampleTracker"
SAR application id for kinesis-stream-device-data-to-amazon-location-tracker app
ApplicationId="arn:aws:serverlessrepo:us-east-1:003883091127:applications/kinesis-stream-device-data-to-amazon-location-tracker"
if [ -z "$AWS_REGION" ]; then
echo "Error: AWS_REGION is not set. You may set the environment variable with this command: 'export AWS_REGION=us-east-1'."
exit 1
fi
echo "Deploying kinesis data stream template for sample app."
aws cloudformation deploy 
--template-file src/cfn_template/kinesisResources.yml 
--stack-name TrackingAndGeofencingSampleKinesisStack 
--region ${AWS_REGION} \
echo "Retrieving TrackingAndGeofencingSampleKinesisDataStreamARN from the created CloudFormation stack."
Retrieve the KinesisDataStreamARN output from the deployed stack
KinesisDataStreamARN=$(aws cloudformation describe-stacks 
--stack-name TrackingAndGeofencingSampleKinesisStack 
--query "Stacks[0].Outputs[?OutputKey=='TrackingAndGeofencingSampleKinesisDataStreamARN'].OutputValue" 
--output text 
--region "${AWS_REGION}")
Check if KinesisDataStreamARN was retrieved successfully
if [ -z "$KinesisDataStreamARN" ]; then echo "Error: Failed to retrieve TrackingAndGeofencingSampleKinesisDataStreamARN from CloudFormation stack." exit 1 fi
`echo "Creating changeset kinesis-stream-device-data-to-location-tracker Serverless Application with kinesis data stream: $KinesisDataStreamARN."
ChangeSetName="kinesis-stream-device-data-to-location-tracker-change-set"
SarStackName="kinesis-stream-device-data-to-location-tracker-app-stack"
ChangeSetId=$(aws serverlessrepo create-cloud-formation-change-set 
--application-id "${ApplicationId}" 
--capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM 
--region "${AWS_REGION}" 
--stack-name "$SarStackName" 
--change-set-name "$ChangeSetName" 
--parameter-overrides Name="TrackerName",Value="${TrackerName}" Name="EventBridgeEnabled",Value="true" Name="KinesisStreamArn",Value="${KinesisDataStreamARN}" 
--query 'ChangeSetId' 
--output text)`
Check if ChangeSetId was captured successfully
if [ -z "$ChangeSetId" ]; then echo "Error: Failed to capture ChangeSetId from the create-cloud-formation-change-set output." exit 1 fi
Sleep for 5 seconds to allow the change set to be created.
sleep 5
Changes=$(aws cloudformation describe-change-set --change-set-name "$ChangeSetName" --stack-name "$SarStackName" --query "Changes" --output text)
echo "$Changes"
if [[ -z "$Changes" || "$Changes" = "None" ]]; then
echo "No changes to deploy. Stack serverlessrepo-$SarStackName is up to date."
else
echo "Executing change set: $ChangeSetId"
Retry logic for executing the change set to avoid calling the execute API too fast.
` max_attempts=5
attempt=1
while [ "$attempt" -le "$max_attempts" ]; do
echo "Attempt $attempt of $max_attempts: Executing change set $ChangeSetId"
execute_output=$(aws cloudformation execute-change-set --change-set-name "$ChangeSetId" --region "$AWS_REGION" 2>&1)
execute_status=$?

if [ "$execute_status" -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "Change set executed successfully: $ChangeSetId. You can go to CloudFormation's console to monitor the deployment progress."
  break
fi

if [ "$attempt" -eq "$max_attempts" ]; then
  echo "Maximum execution attempts reached, failing execution."
  exit 1
fi

((attempt++))
sleep 1

done
fi
sleep 2 # Wait for 2 seconds for the previous stack deployment to finish the tracker creation.
echo "Deploying cloudformation template for sample app using TrackerName: $TrackerName and region: $AWS_REGION."
aws cloudformation deploy 
--template-file src/cfn_template/locationResources.yml 
--stack-name TrackingAndGeofencingSample 
--parameter-overrides TrackerName="${TrackerName}" 
--region "${AWS_REGION}" 
--capabilities CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM
echo "All deployments complete!"*`
I have tried to copy templates for creating CloudFormation, but i seem not to understand.
If anyone can point me to a youtube video that can help, i will appreciate.
